# How to apply JoltTransformJson over an attribute value in NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I am receiving a request payload using HandleHttpRequest processor and I am reading the Jolt Spec from an external file using FetchFile processor.
I need to apply Jolt transformation for the request payload.
When I pass the specification to JoltTransformJSON processor using a variable (spec_name), it is not applied to the request payload. Instead it is applied to the spec_name value itself.

Below is my NiFi Flow
[image: NiFi Flow]

These are the attributes in the Queue before passing to the JoltTransformJson processor
[image: attributes before JoltTransformJson]

The specification used in JoltTransformJson
[image: JoltTransformJson]

Output after transformation
`{"parent":{"database_id":"parent.database_id"},"properties":"properties"}`

The expected result is the transformation needs to be applied over the payload data.

**Input payload**

```
{
  "database_id": "c3c82c23-5203-491e-8043-c205357087a0",
  "column_details": {
    "Name": {
      "type": "title",
      "title": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": {
            "content": "NiFi"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Jolt Spec**

```
{
   "database_id": "parent.database_id",
   "column_details": "properties"
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "parent" : {
    "database_id" : "c3c82c23-5203-491e-8043-c205357087a0"
  },
  "properties" : {
    "Name" : {
      "type" : "title",
      "title" : [ {
        "type" : "text",
        "text" : {
          "content" : "NiFi"
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clearly state the current input,output, and expected JSON values as texts?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Please find the updated details above. I have added Input and Output payload. The catch here is we are having intermediate steps between the request processor and jolt processor. Hence the payload (which is an attribute variable) is not considered as the input data while transformation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Vignesh. You have already solved your problem. Just nest your current spec within a shift transformation template such as `[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "database_id": "parent.database_id",
      "column_details": "properties"
    }
  }
]`

Comment: Hey @BarbarosÖzhan If you could please find the above screenshot (The specification used in JoltTransformJson), we have the config to mention the spec operation {shift} as one of the properties in the NiFi processor. 
Clarifying the issue again, the data over which the Jolt transformation is happening is the result fetched from the File in the previous step. But we expect the transformation to be performed over the initial request payload which we have as an attribute in the payload variable.